# linear calendar first day is Monday, change to Sunday

Tags: php

how can i change the first day in the first column of weeks into Sunday.

here's the code i got from a website, and I've been trying to change the position of the days but still it displays the first day of the week as Monday. how can i change it to Sunday, thanks in advance :)

```
<?php

$dDaysOnPage = 37;
$dDay = 1;

if (isset($_REQUEST['year']))
{
    if ($_REQUEST['year'] <> "") 
    { 
        $dYear = $_REQUEST['year']; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $dYear = date("Y"); 
    }
}
else
{
    $_REQUEST['year'] = date("Y");
    $dYear = $_REQUEST['year'];
}
?>

<table style="margin-left:-80px;" class="table table-bordered">
    <tr class="blue">
        <td><?php echo $dYear; ?></td>
        <th>Mo</th>   <!--i change this to Sunday-->
        <th>Tu</th>
        <th>We</th>
        <th>Th</th>
        <th>Fr</th>
        <th>Sa</th>
        <th>Su</th>
        <th>Mo</th>
        <th>Tu</th>
        <th>We</th>
        <th>Th</th>
        <th>Fr</th>
        <th>Sa</th>
        <th>Su</th>
        <th>Mo</th>
        <th>Tu</th>
        <th>We</th>
        <th>Th</th>
        <th>Fr</th>
        <th>Sa</th>
        <th>Su</th>
        <th>Mo</th>
        <th>Tu</th>
        <th>We</th>
        <th>Th</th>
        <th>Fr</th>
        <th>Sa</th>
        <th>Su</th>
        <th>Mo</th>
        <th>Tu</th>
        <th>We</th>
        <th>Th</th>
        <th>Fr</th>
        <th>Sa</th>
        <th>Su</th>
        <th>Mo</th>
        <th>Tu</th>
    </tr>                                   
    <?php
    function FriendlyDayOfWeek($dayNum) {
    // converts the sunday to 7
    // This function can be removed in php 5 by - date("N"),
    // just remove function calls below and replace by swapping date("w" for date("N"
    if ($dayNum == 0){ return 7; } else { return $dayNum; }
    }

    function InsertBlankTd($numberOfTdsToAdd) {
    for($i=1;$i<=$numberOfTdsToAdd;$i++) {
    $tdString .= "<td></td>";
    }
    return $tdString;
    }

    for ($mC=1;$mC<=12;$mC++) {
    $currentDT = mktime(0,0,0,$mC,$dDay,$dYear);
    echo "<tr><td class='monthName'><div>".date("M",$currentDT)."</div></td>";
        $daysInMonth = date("t",$currentDT);

        echo InsertBlankTd(FriendlyDayOfWeek(date("w",$currentDT))-1);

        for ($i=1;$i<=$daysInMonth;$i++) {
        $exactDT = mktime(0,0,0,$mC,$i,$dYear);
        if ($i==date("d")&&date("m",$currentDT)==date("m")) { $class="currentDay"; } else { $class = ""; }
        echo "<td class='".$class." days day".FriendlyDayOfWeek(date("w",$exactDT))."'>".$i."</td>";
        }

        echo InsertBlankTd($dDaysOnPage - $daysInMonth - FriendlyDayOfWeek(date("w",$currentDT))+1);
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change the column you specified in the table (where you put `<!--i change this to Sunday-->`. Add `<th>Su</th>` after `<td><?php echo $dYear; ?></td>` and remove the last `<th>Tu</th>` before `</tr>`. Like this:

```
   <td><?php echo $dYear; ?></td>
   <th>Su</th>
   <th>Mo</th>   <!--i change this to Sunday-->
   <th>Tu</th>
   <!-- etc. -->
   <th>Su</th>
   <th>Mo</th>
</tr>
```

Second, adjust the number of blank `<td>`s you insert before the first day of the month and after the first day of the month.

```
// First change here, remove the -1 at the end
echo InsertBlankTd(FriendlyDayOfWeek(date("w",$currentDT)));

for ($i=1;$i<=$daysInMonth;$i++) {
$exactDT = mktime(0,0,0,$mC,$i,$dYear);
if ($i==date("d")&&date("m",$currentDT)==date("m")) { $class="currentDay"; } else { $class = ""; }
   echo "<td class='".$class." days day".FriendlyDayOfWeek(date("w",$exactDT))."'>".$i."</td>";
}

// Second change here, remove the +1 at the end
echo InsertBlankTd($dDaysOnPage - $daysInMonth - FriendlyDayOfWeek(date("w",$currentDT)));
```

Third, there is a warning inside function `InsertBlankTd()` due to undefined `$tdString`. You need to add `$tdString = '';` before beginning your for() loop, like so:

```
function InsertBlankTd($numberOfTdsToAdd) {
   $tdString = '';
   for($i=1;$i<=$numberOfTdsToAdd;$i++) {
   // ... the rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your $currentDT variable in strtotime() like this:

```
echo InsertBlankTd(FriendlyDayOfWeek(date("w", strtotime($currentDT . ' -1 day')))-1);
```

Quick edit:

If this doesn't work, try using this same method in a different place where it prints out the days. I didn't test the code...